# Get Count(*) from multiple tables using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Registration_Table` and `ApplicationStatus_Table`. I have taken one column only from `Registration_Table` for understanding purpose. In `ApplicationStatus_Table` based on dates of Registrationdate and FinalSubmissiondate check the status.

Registration_Table

```
 Registrationdate
 -----------------------
 2016-12-22 12:52:48.493
 2016-12-21 15:05:24.533
```

ApplicationStatus_Table

```
FinalSubmissiondate              InnovationStatus
-------------------------------------------------
2016-12-22 12:52:48.493          Completed
2016-12-21 15:05:24.533           11
```

I need result like below.

```
 Registrationdate    RegistrationsCount   InnovationsStatus
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 2016-12-22               1                1
 2016-12-21               1                0
```

I need result on particular date how many Registrations and InnovationsStatus. If InnovationStatus completed means 1 and others all 0.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: As I mention in question using sql server. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: The question says "using SQL" - SQL is a query language, not a specific DBMS product

Comment: Which one? MySQL, MSSQL, postgres, oracle, etc? SQL is the language. #rtfm

Comment: I need sql query for display counts like that above using sql server 2008. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I need sql query for display the counts like mention in my above question. @KoenHollander

Answer (score 2):

Consider an aggregate query with a full count and conditional count. Below also extracts the time part from datetime value with zero return in conditional aggregate:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, r.Registrationdate) As [Date], Count(*) As RegistrationsCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.Status = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As InnovationsStatus
FROM Registration_Table r
INNER JOIN ApplicationStatus_Table a
ON r.Registrationdate = a.FinalSubmissiondate
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, r.Registrationdate)
```

Comment: @MMK Maybe you have a null column in some of the records. Try `count(1) as RegistrationsCount`

Comment: @MMK With the given schema in the question,this should work. +1 from my side.

Comment: @MMK - Please clarify as I do not understand your comment.

Comment: FinalSubmissiondate have some null date but I added count(1) as RegistrationsCount then also not showing. @Parfait

Comment: I added like data conversion then working fine ON CONVERT(date, r.Registrationdate) = CONVERT(date, a.FinalSubmissiondate) but count showing rong, there is 2 registration only showing 6 regisstraiton count   Date RegistrationsCount InnovationsStatus
          2016-12-06     6                            6

Comment: Does *RegistrationsCount* not show or returns NULL -two very different things? Removing time part of datetime, would show more matches as data contains more entries within same day, hence 6 per. For this answer, I do not know how or why *RegistrationsCount* returns empty. Is *InnovationsStatus* empty as well? Must be data/type issues. Please post a few data rows of both tables (with matching datetimes).

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like:**

```
SELECT  CAST(r.Registrationdate AS DATE) AS as Registrationdate,
        COUNT(Registrationdate) OVER (PARTITION BY Registrationdate) AS RegistrationsCount,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  a.InnovationStatus='Completed' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as InnovationsStatus
FROM Registration_Table   r
INNER JOIN ApplicationStatus_Table  a
ON a.FinalSubmissiondate=r.Registrationdate
GROUP BY r.Registrationdate
ORDER BY r.Registrationdate DESC
```

**Test Data:**

```
create table #Registration_Table (
 Registrationdate datetime
)

insert into #Registration_Table
values('2016-12-22 12:52:48.493'),('2016-12-21 15:05:24.533')

create table #ApplicationStatus_Table(
 FinalSubmissiondate datetime,
 InnovationStatus varchar(20)
) 

insert into #ApplicationStatus_Table
values ('2016-12-22 12:52:48.493','Completed'),('2016-12-21 15:05:24.533','11')



SELECT  CAST(r.Registrationdate AS DATE),
        COUNT(Registrationdate) OVER (PARTITION BY Registrationdate) AS RegistrationsCount,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  a.InnovationStatus='Completed' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as InnovationsStatus
FROM #Registration_Table   r
INNER JOIN #ApplicationStatus_Table  a
ON a.FinalSubmissiondate=r.Registrationdate
GROUP BY r.Registrationdate
ORDER BY r.Registrationdate DESC
```

**Result:**

```
  Registrationdate       RegistrationsCount InnovationsStatus
     2016-12-22                 1                1
     2016-12-21                 1                0
```

Comment: Getting error: Incorrect syntax near 'Registrationdate'. @Jibin Balachandran

Comment: @MMK I have updated my answer. Please do check and let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Date format should like that 2016-12-22. @Jibin Balachandran

Comment: @MMK Ya, you will get it it like that only since we are casting datetime as date.

Answer (score 0):

```
         *****Using this query*****

 select t1.[Registrationdate],
 COUNT(t1.[Registrationdate]) as [RegistrationsCount],
 max(case when t2.[InnovationStatus]='completed' then 1 else 0 end) as [InnovationStatus]
 from [#yourtable1] t1
 Join [#youttable2] t2 on
 t1.[Registrationdate]=t2.[FinalSubmissiondate]
 Group by t1.[Registrationdate] Order by t1.[Registraiondate] Desc;
```